# In Apache Flink, how to achieve the same effect like reduceByKeyAndWindow provided by Apache

Tags: apache-flink

In Apache Spark Streaming, *reduceByKeyAndWindow* enable the user to provide an inverse function when the old data is expired. The programmer can use this function to decrease the count value for the removed event.

I'm wondering how to achieve the same effect in Apache Flink.

Comment: I think this is a performance aspect that Flink does not use, because its window implementation works. a bit different.

Answer (score 1):

This is a Spark-specific construct that Flink does not use, because its window implementation works different. It is used for sliding windows, to "undo" aggregation".

Since Flink does not need to do a final aggregation across mini batches (but simply across internal panes), and does not need to align windows to mini batches, this trick is not necessary, it also works very fast without.